# Is there a function for Breusch-Pagan Test for feols regression from fixest package?

Tags: r, regression

I am looking to conduct a Breusch-Pagan Test for my regression. For a `lm` regression  this can be done with the function `bptest()` from the `lmtest` package.  However, this funciton does not work with `feols` regressions as shown below in an example.

```
library(fixest)
library(car)
library(lmtest)

model<- feols(conc ~ uptake + Treatment | Type, CO2, vcov = "hetero")
summary(model)

bptest(model)
```

Is there a function to conduct this test for feols regressions? Due to the size of my data set and a large number of fixed effects in my model, running my regression instead as an `lm` function with fixed effects as factors is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible because the `bptest` only accepts `lm` objects like mentioned in the documentation for argument `formula`:

> a symbolic description for the model to be tested (or a fitted "lm"
> object).

Here a reproducible example using `mtcars` data:

```r
library(fixest)
library(lmtest)
model1 <- lm(mpg~disp+hp, data=mtcars)
bptest(model1)
#> 
#>  studentized Breusch-Pagan test
#> 
#> data:  model1
#> BP = 4.0861, df = 2, p-value = 0.1296
model2 <- feols(mpg~disp+hp, data=mtcars)
bptest(model2)
#> Error in eval(predvars, data, env): object 'mpg' not found
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Error because does not accept `feols`.

Comment: As per my above question, looking for a function to conduct the equivalent of a bptest for an feols regression.